# Vmware 5.1 ESX linux host cpu keep climbing overtime

Tags: vmware-esx, cpu-usage, debian-lenny

I have Debian lenny with php and mysql, in Vmware 5.1 ESX.

Cpu keeps climbing over time. After about 50 days, cpu usage is 100% by apache and mysql but it is climbing day by day. If I restart these processes, nothing changes. cpu usage rises to the top again.  Response time of the web server is also climbing bit by bit day by day.

When I reboot this server, everything becomes normal until a few week pass. I repeated this scenario 3 times.

What is a possible problem? When I searched, I met such a situation which is similar to us, but there is VMware 2.x. [VMware Host CPU Usage Climbing](https://serverfault.com/questions/54427/vmware-host-cpu-usage-climbing)

Comment: What processes are using the CPU?

Comment: It shows apache and mysql using most of the cpu. But after this situation we moved mysql to an other server, then apache started to use most of cpu

Comment: And restarting Apache doesn't provide any change in the behavior at all - not even temporary relief from the CPU use?

Comment: When apache stopped it became normal. But when I started apache again, it was suddenly rising to top in 1 or 2 secs.